# Delete document when partition key comes as child row c# cosmos DB

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I have a collection with JSON Document

```
{
"type": "OrderHistory",
"values": [
    {       
        "CustomerId": "8990",
        "DeliveryInstructions": "",
        "UpdateDate": "2020-02-07T14:33:50",
        "OrderId": "00716",

        "Items": [
            {
                "ProductId": "402",

            }
        ],
        "id": "0071661617+Settled"
    }
],
"id": "c57ab11a-2aec-45a4-a3e8-063598e15061",
"_rid": "9-kVAPFOVXkBAAAAAAAAAA==",
"_self": "dbs/9-kVAA==/colls/9-kVAPFOVXk=/docs/9-kVAPFOVXkBAAAAAAAAAA==/",
"_etag": "\"35008246-0000-0200-0000-5e8dc41a0000\"",
"_attachments": "attachments/",
"_ts": 1586349082
}
```

The thing is here CustomerId is partitionkey .We have to delete the records based on conditions .I have used below method for delteing records which works fine with normal json which havent childrows.May be because parition value comes as childrow value ,Its not working as expected.

```
   ///Deleting records from collection based on documentId  
    private async static Task DeleterecordByDocumentID(DocumentClient client, string databaseName, 
    string collectionName, string documentName, string Partitionkeyvalue)
    {
        var docUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(databaseName, collectionName, documentName);
        RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new 
        PartitionKey(Partitionkeyvalue) };
        var deleteresponse = await client.DeleteDocumentAsync(docUri, options);
    }
```

It would be helpful if anyone can suggest method to delete cosmos DB record in which partition key appears as child row .Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share your container definition? I am wondering how you have defined the partition key there (I mean how have you specified the path)?

Answer (score 0):

Your above method looks similar, Below method is working for me.

**Delete Document with partitionKey**

```
public virtual async Task<bool> DeleteAsync(string databaseId, string collectionId, string id, string partitionKey)
    {
        await client.DeleteDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(databaseId, collectionId, id), new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(partitionKey) });
        return true;
    }
```

**Delete Document without partitionKey**

```
public virtual async Task<bool> DeleteAsync(string databaseId, string collectionId, string id)
    {
        await client.DeleteDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(databaseId, collectionId, id));
        return true;
    }
```